Manage an indirect Relationship between three tables on PowerBI
I have three tables, a sales table with :

client

product

date

quantity


A client table which is the list of cients
and my third table is very specific. For each group and during a special time interval a client is part of a group
for example Client A is in group 1 for flour between september 2023 and december 2024  and in group 2 for water between august 2022 and january 2024.

sales has a many to one relationship with clients

client has a one to many relationship to with groups


because the clients appear several times in sales and group I can't connect directly the two tables.
I want to calculate the sales by group. Can you help me ?
I tried some measures with RELATED but the lack direct relationship gives me the wrong result

Can you please provide some data ?

I suggest summarizing, summarize all and use merge data, inserting all the data into a single table, I used a simple relationship in bi to obtain data and it didn't work correctly. I had to insert data from the other table that I also wanted to obtain into the query source table.

I cannot provide data I'm sorry, it's work related and it's confidential :(

I would model your case in a different way which is star schema :
Sales : fact table
Client : dimension
Group : dimension
Dates : dimension
In the Sales you may need a column SalesKey that combines the client and product as a unique identifier for each sale.
And in the Group, the same thing you need to create a similar  column GroupKey that combines Client and Product to form a matching key.
Meanwhile if you want to keep the same model you have, you need to create a calculated table :
SalesByGroup = 
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(Sales, Group),
        Sales[Client] = Group[Client] &&  
        Sales[Product] = Group[Product] && 
        Sales[Date] >= Group[Start Date] &&  
        Sales[Date] <= Group[End Date] 
    ),
    "Client", Sales[Client],
    "Product", Sales[Product],
    "Date", Sales[Date],
    "Quantity", Sales[Quantity],
    "Group", Group[Group],
    "Start Date", Group[Start Date],
    "End Date", Group[End Date]
)

Then you create a measure based on this calculated table :
Total Sales by Group = SUM(SalesByGroup[Quantity])


